# How can I append the date to the input field?

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can I append the date to the input field?

```
<label>Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="datek" class="form-control" placeholder="date naissance">
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the date of this day??

Comment: yes display date of this day

Comment: for example display 15/06/2019 ,it shows me dd / mm / yyyy

Comment: Check the below solution. Have made a working snippet for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery or JS

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $('#datePicker').val(today);
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<label>Date:</label>
<input type="date" id="datePicker" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="date naissance">
</div>
```

Comment: Glad that I could help you out. Happy coding :)